Dynamic Transpose of Rows to Columns in Databricks SQL
I just have started to work with Databricks SQL.
Here I have a table that contains for each article a list of attributes and values following this structure:
Article Attribute   Value
A   Name    Bike S
A   Size    5
A   Price   4
A   Costs   3
A   Department  CR
B   Name    Bike M
B   Size    5
B   Price   4
C   Name    Bike L

As you can see not every attribute exists for each article.
Now, using Databricks SQL, how is it possible to transpose the rows to columns to get this result?


SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT
    Article,
    Attribute,
    Value
  FROM
    articles
) AS source_table
PIVOT (
  MAX(Value) FOR Attribute IN ('Name', 'Size', 'Price', 'Costs', 'Department')
) AS pivot_table
ORDER BY Article;

